# Can the GET variables be extracted?

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I'm trying to store GET variables using PHP from this URL string, but doesn't seem to be working...

> domain.local/welcome?fwd=cd&data=%7B"email"%3A"example%40example.co.uk"%7D

The PHP I tried is:

```
$email = htmlspecialchars($_GET["email"]);
```

and also...

```
$email = $_GET["email"];
```

Neither is working, Any ideas please? (BTW I have no means to change the URL string)

Comment: It should be in `$_GET['data']`. `email` is not a parameter in that URL. Looks like it is JSON being sent via GET.. https://eval.in/668689

Comment: Thanks Chris85 for spotting this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this :

> your url is :
>   domain.local/welcome??fwd=cd&data={"email":"example@example.co.uk"}

```
<?php
$fwd = $_GET['fwd']; //output cd
$data = json_decode($_GET['data']); //

echo $data->email; //output is example@example.co.uk
?>
```

> if your url like
>   data={"email":"example@example.co.uk","name":"myname","mobile":123456"}

Then you can use bellow example :

```
echo $data->name; //output myname
echo $data->mobile; //output 123456
```

Comment: Thanks @razibalmamun. This looks good, however I'm still struggling to get any output with your code. I'm using MAMP 3 on a Mac using PHP 5.5.23 (if this helps any).

Also, I've added the following into MAMP php.ini after a little googling...

`magic_quotes_gpc = Off`
 and 
`magic_quotes_runtime = Off`

Comment: If my answer is useful for you please accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: I've added this immediately after your code... `echo json_last_error_msg();` and it returns `Syntax error`

Comment: follow this json error documention http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: I've added the code on that page and it looks like it's returning no error, but it's still not working unfortunately

Comment: but, i have checked my code this run perfectly my localhost. i have used `AMPPS`

Comment: I've just deployed this to my server also and still doesn't return anything. It would have anything to do with this being wordpress would it?

Comment: i thinks yes, try it

Comment: Just tried your code on MAMP outside of wordpress and it works perfectly

Comment: Just got it working with `$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['data']));`